# How to use toList to deserialize datatable when there is a field name with empty space?

Tags: c#, json, .net, datatable, deserialization

I have a `Datatable` like below structure,

```
[
   {
        "Product P/N": "12",
        "Brand": "A"
   },
   {
        "Product P/N": "34",
        "Brand": "B"
   }
]
```

Then, I try to make it as a `TableData`. But `Product P/N` is all null.

```cs
var table = this.DataTable.ToList<TableData>();
var a = table.FirstOrDefault().ProductPN;   //  null
var b = table.FirstOrDefault().Brand;       //  A
```

DataTable Extension:

```cs
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
{
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
    IList<T> result = new List<T>();

    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        var item = MappingItem<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
        result.Add(item);
    }

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Class:

```cs
public class TableData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Product P/N")]
    public string ProductPN{ get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

MappingItem

```cs
private static T MappingItem<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
{
    T item = new T();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var PtName = property.Name;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.ToDescription()) && row.Table.Columns.Contains(property.ToDescription()))
        {
            PtName = property.ToDescription();
        }

        if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(PtName))
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (row[PtName] != null && row[PtName] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, row[PtName].ToString(), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, string.Empty, null);
                }
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            {
                if (row[PtName].ToString().ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, true, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, false, null);
                }
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                if (row[PtName] != DBNull.Value && DateTime.TryParse(row[PtName].ToString(), out dt))
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, dt, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, null, null);
                }
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
            {
                decimal val = new decimal();
                decimal.TryParse(row[PtName].ToString(), out val);
                property.SetValue(item, val, null);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?))
            {
                if (row[PtName] == DBNull.Value || row[PtName].ToString() == null)
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal val = new decimal();
                    decimal.TryParse(row[PtName].ToString(), out val);
                    property.SetValue(item, val, null);
                }
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(double))
            {
                decimal val = new decimal();
                decimal.TryParse(row[PtName].ToString(), out val);
                property.SetValue(item, Convert.ToDouble(val), null);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Int16))
            {
                decimal val = new decimal();
                decimal.TryParse(row[PtName].ToString(), out val);
                property.SetValue(item, Convert.ToInt16(val), null);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
            {
                decimal val = new decimal();
                decimal.TryParse(row[PtName].ToString(), out val);
                property.SetValue(item, Convert.ToInt32(val), null);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Int64))
            {
                decimal val = new decimal();
                decimal.TryParse(row[PtName].ToString(), out val);
                property.SetValue(item, Convert.ToInt64(val), null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (row[PtName] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    property.SetValue(item, row[PtName], null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

ToDescription():

```cs
public static string ToDescription(this PropertyInfo Object)
{
    object[] attrs = Object.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Display), false);
    if (null != attrs && attrs.Length > 0) return ((Display)attrs[0]).Text;
    return Object.Name.ToString();
}
```

**How can I actually get name field with space or special character ?**

Comment: `MappingItem` can you share the code of this method?

Comment: @Chetan I update my post with MappingItem

Comment: Can you share `ToDescription()` method? Is it a extension method?

Comment: @YongShun  I update my post with `ToDescription()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `ProductPN` property, you are applying `JsonProperty` attribute which is not `Display` attribute as in `ToDescription()` method.

Hence you will get the default property name.

**Solution**

To avoid the break of the existing `ToDescription()` method, you need to apply this logic:

1. Retrieve attribute from `JsonPropertyAttribute`.
2. Retrieve attribute from `DisplayAttribute`.
3. Return default `Property.Name`.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static string ToDescription(this PropertyInfo property)
{
    try
    {
        object[] descriptionAttrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), false);
        if (descriptionAttrs != null && descriptionAttrs.Length > 0)
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute description = (JsonPropertyAttribute)descriptionAttrs[0];         
            return description.PropertyName;
        }

        object[] attrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
        if (null != attrs && attrs.Length > 0) 
            return ((DisplayAttribute)attrs[0]).Name;
        
        return property.Name.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Sample Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TzWih7)

Comment: Works like a charm. `[Display("Product P/N")]` also sovled my problem without modify `ToDescription()` Thanks!